# Difficulty invoking WCF POST service running on localhost in a test project in same solution as service

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, config

I am having trouble developing and testing a POST web service which both receives and returns JSON. 
I am testing it (or trying/wanting to test it) by calling it from a form in a test project within the same 
solution as the web service. However it seems that no matter what I do, I'm getting either a "Bad Request", or 
a "Not Found" error when invoking the service.

There are oodles of posts on the web in relation to these things, and WCF in general, with examples etc, but I 
cannot seem to solve the problem and it's quite disheartening :-((.

I am using VS 2010 on (don't laugh) win XP. However I don't see why an outdated OS should matter.

The single method's signature is

```
public Stream ReceiveCardStatusInfo(Stream request)
```

I have generated a proxy via svcutil, but I'm not using it. I have tried referencing the webservice project as
both an ordinary and a service reference (currently a service reference). The properties of the projects are 
pretty much the defaults, but in trying to resolve the issues, the web page of the WS project currently shows 
"Use Visual Studio Development Server" with "Specific Port" selected, port number 1318. (Virtual Path is the 
default "/").

As I'm not really sure exactly what the problem is, I am providing all my code and config files; 
the Form's logic first (used to invoke the service) and the app.config for that project, with the service
components following:

Form1:

```
public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
}

public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:1318/ReceiveData.svc/ReceiveCardStatusInfo"); // /ReceiveCardStatusInfo
  request.ContentType = "text/json";
  request.Method = "POST";

  string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new {
    AuthenticationToken = "...",
    Campus = "Te Awamutu",
    StudentID = "200122327",
    EnrolmentEndDate = "11/06/2015",
    CardStatus = "Suspended",
    SuspendedDate = "18/08/2014",
    OrderedDate = "20/09/2014",
    ReprintDate = "07/10/2014"
  });

  using (var sW = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream())) {
    sW.Write(json);
    sW.Flush();
    sW.Close();
  }

  var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
  string result;
  using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())) {
    result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
  }

  MessageBox.Show(result);
}
```

app.config (I don't really understand exactly what needs to be in this file, but I've had trouble finding a
clear answer to this, so it contains what it does):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="StudentCardStatusData.ReceiveData" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehaviour">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="StudentCardStatusData.IReceiveData" behaviorConfiguration="web"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="serviceBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpBinding_IReceiveData" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:1318/ReceiveData.svc" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBinding_IReceiveData" contract="IReceiveData" name="webHttpBinding_IReceiveData"/>
      <!-- endpoint address="..." binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IReceiveData" contract="IReceiveData"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_IReceiveData" / -->
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup>
</configuration>
```

Web Service:

IReceiveData:

```
namespace StudentCardStatusData {
  [DataContract]
  public class StatusInfo {
    private string _Authent;
    private string _Campus;
    private string _StudentID;
    private string _EnrolmentEndDate;
    private string _CardStatus;
    private string _SuspendedDate;
    private string _OrderedDate;
    private string _ReprintDate;

    [DataMember(Name="AuthenticationToken")]
    public string AuthenticationToken {
      get { return _Authent; }
      set { _Authent = value; }
    }

    [DataMember(Name="Campus")]
    public String Campus {
      get { return _Campus; }
      set { _Campus = value; }
    }
    [DataMember(Name="StudentID")]
    public String StudentID {
      get { return _StudentID; }
      set { _StudentID = value; }
    }
    [DataMember(Name="EnrolmentEndDate")]
    public String EnrolmentEndDate {
      get { return _EnrolmentEndDate; }
      set { _EnrolmentEndDate = value; }
    }
    [DataMember(Name="CardStatus")]
    public String CardStatus {
      get { return _CardStatus; }
      set { _CardStatus = value; }
    }
    [DataMember(Name="SuspendedDate")]
    public String SuspendedDate {
      get { return _SuspendedDate; }
      set { _SuspendedDate = value; }
    }
    [DataMember(Name = "OrderedDate")]
    public String OrderedDate {
      get { return _OrderedDate; }
      set { _OrderedDate = value; }
    }
    [DataMember(Name = "ReprintDate")]
    public String ReprintDate {
      get { return _ReprintDate; }
      set { _ReprintDate = value; }
    }
  }

  [ServiceContract]
  public interface IReceiveData {
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
               RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
               ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
               BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
               UriTemplate = "ReceiveCardStatusInfo")]
    Stream ReceiveCardStatusInfo(Stream request);
  }
}
```

ReceiveData.svc:

```
namespace StudentCardStatusData {

  public class ReceiveData : IReceiveData {

    public Stream ReceiveCardStatusInfo(Stream request) {
      Stream res = new MemoryStream();
      StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(res);
      try {
        ConnectionStringSettings _DefaultSetting = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Take2"];
        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(_DefaultSetting.ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = cnn;
        //
        if (request != null) {
          StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(request);
          var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
          List<StatusInfo> allitems = serializer.Deserialize<List<StatusInfo>>(sr.ReadToEnd());
          bool isFirst = true;

          foreach (var item in allitems) {
            if (isFirst) {
              cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
              cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Cast(AuthenticationKey as varchar(50)) FROM IDCardAuthentication";
              cmd.Connection.Open();
              object o = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
              cmd.Connection.Close();
              if ((string)o != item.AuthenticationToken.ToUpper()) {
                sw.Write("[{\"Result\":\"Undefined Failure\"}]");
                return res;
              }
              isFirst = false;
            }
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "dbo.spSaveStudentCardStatus";
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Campus", item.Campus));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PerID", item.StudentID));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EndDate", item.EnrolmentEndDate));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Status", item.CardStatus));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Upload", item.SuspendedDate));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Ordered", item.OrderedDate));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Reprint", item.ReprintDate));
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Connection.Close();
          }
        }
        sw.Write("[{\"Result\":\"Success\"}]");
        return res;
      }
      catch (Exception ex) {
        sw.Write("[{\"Result\":\"" + ex.Message + "\"}]");
        return res;
     }
    }
  }
}
```

Web.Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Take2"
      connectionString="..."
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>


  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="StudentCardStatusData.ReceiveData" behaviorConfiguration="StudentCardStatusData.ReceiveDataBehavior"> 
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="StudentCardStatusData.IReceiveData" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="https://localhost:1318/ReceiveData.svc" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="StudentCardStatusData.ReceiveDataBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>


  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Please explain "I am testing it (or trying/wanting to test it) by calling it from a form in a test project within the same solution as the web service."

Comment: My comment (or trying/wanting to test it) relates to my inability to successfully invoke the service for no reason that I can determine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very first requirement to consume any service is that “Service is Up and Running on Service” here in local ISS in your case.

The reason for getting "Bad Request", or a "Not Found" error when invoking the service is possibility that it is not running on server (localhost).

Are you able to view service page from browser by HTTP request of page "ReceiveData.svc" on your endpoints.

If not then you have to make sure that your service is all ready running before you start consuming it.

As you said that you are running it from same solutions, I am sure you are stating multiple application at the same time. I mean that the Service Application and Consuming Application.

If not you can run multiple start up application from same solution by settings in

Go to Solution properties -> Common properties -> Start up Project and select Multiple start up projects.

So now when you run the solution your both application will start and you should be able to use service.

**EDIT**

I created test application with all your given code..!!

And it gave me same error..!!!!
So I changed;

```
  request.ContentType = "'text/json; charset=utf-8'";
```

and it worked..!!! ;)

So please try that.
Hope it helps..!!

Comment: Yes I can view the service help page from a browser. Yes the project is set to start both projects, with the webservice set to start without debugging.

Comment: Awesome, with that change I've been able to finish it and deploy it. Thank you.